# If $f:[0,a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continous for all $a>0$ then $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:[0,a] \subset \mathbb{R}_+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

**Question.** If $f$ is well defined and continuous for all $a>0$, then can I assert that $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \longrightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ is also well defined and continous?

I think so, since $a>0$ is arbitrary. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes. Your argument is correct.

Comment: What if $f$ depends on $a$ though? Something like $f(x)=ax$? Would it makes sense to extend $f$ over $\Bbb R^+$?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Great question. But I don't know. What you think?

Comment: I would say $f:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R$ is not well defined. But I would appreciate @EthanBolker's feedback as well.

Comment: @EthanBolker could you justify your claim?

Comment: Continuity is a pointwise statement. $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}_+$ if for every $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$, $f$ is continuous at $x$. Can you show $f$ is continuous at every $x$ with your assumptions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f \notin C(\mathbb R^+)$. Then, there exists some $x_0>0$ such that $$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) \neq f(x_0)$$
But since $a$ is arbitrary, we can choose $a = x_0+1$. Then, as the statement provides $f:[0, x_0+1] \to \mathbb R$ should be continuous at $x_0$. Contradiction!

Hence, our assumption was wrong and $f\in C(\mathbb{R^+})$.

Comment: This is correct. It would be even nicer written as a direct argument rather than a proof by contradiction.